# UIWebview Facebook Connect

Tags: uiwebview, facebook

Inside a UIWebView the user can click on FB connect button the page displays and when I hit login the UIWebView turns blank and stops there.

On a regular browser after the login is hit, it looks like it goes on fb and redirects back to the webite. I'm not sure what to change on the UIWebView so that it handles it like Safari does

edit:So when I try it on the simulator's safari, hitting the FB Connect button, it opens a new page that shows the login form and then it closes and goes back to the first page after hitting login. SO i guess the question: Is there a way for UIwebView to handle this?

Comment: actually, I'm having the EXACT same problem with facebook authentication + android's Webview.  Anyone know how to handle the redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem was using the regular facebook login as opposed to the m.facebook.com login.
Which avoids creating a pop up.